# Federated identity user pools differentiate social identity provider from SAML external providers

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm trying to integrate cognito user pools with third-party SAML identity providers like Azure and also social identity providers like google or facebook. However, I want to differentiate when the same user (with the same email) logs in either via social sign or the SAML third-party identity provider. This for security reasons as I would like that only users signed using third party identity providers can access enterprise accounts.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito provides Lambda triggers for various events. You can refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) to learn more about them.

For your use case, **Pre token generation Lambda trigger** looks suitable, where you can implement custom code to determine whether a user is coming from a third-party identity provider or not. If so, you can include a custom claim in the token. Later, you can utilize the value of this custom claim in code to detect whether or not a user logged in using a third-party.

- [Pre token generation Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) documentation.
- [How to Use Cognito Pre-Token Generation trigger to Customize Claims In ID Tokens](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/how-to-use-cognito-pre-token-generators-to-customize-claims-in-id-tokens/)